# Drawing animation path on google map in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to draw path on the map in Android and I want that the path line is an animation. I can draw lines in any static color (blue, red etc.) but not an animation. The line must be an animation. [This link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/198/cptx.png/) explains what I want to do.

Tugrul.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not easy thing to do, but if you are using canvas to draw the path, you can use the functions `canvas.translate() canvas.rotate() canvas.scale()` with some sort of timers to achieve what you need, if you are using something else please state it.

Comment: Thx for answer. I am looking for a special method to do that, but there is no information about it. There is many overlays in my application so that it is not easy to use canvas operations. Many overlays locks the app . If I do not find a new methodology, I will use your advice. Thx.